# Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact

Tags: maven, bintray

when running this command to deploy aretifact is says it cannot find it on the repository server. should it now be uploaded first?

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.microbuild3.test -DartifactId=com.microbuild3.com -Dversion=0.0.1 -Dfile=./target/com.microbuild3.test-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war -Durl=https://api.bintray.com/maven/meja0016/microbuild3/com.microbuild3.test -DrepositoryId=bintray
```

Comment: Please post the whole error output...

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project com.microbuild3.test: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.microbuild3.test:com.microbuild3.com:war:0.0.1 in bintray (https://api.bintray.com/maven/meja0016/microbuild3/com.microbuild3.test) ->

Comment: I'm having same error. I have same project which deployed smoothly to repsy.io maven repo. But it did not deploy to bintray because of this error saying cannot find artifact.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your syntax is not following Bintray's [Maven Upload REST API](https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_maven_upload).
Your URL contains your organization name and your name, and it does not contain the repository name.
Your path should be:

```
https://bintray.com/api/v1/maven/microbuild3/:repositoy_name/:package_name/:file_path[;publish=0/1]
```

For more information [Publishing Your Maven Project to Bintray](https://blog.bintray.com/2015/09/17/publishing-your-maven-project-to-bintray/) blog.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory).</sup>